# Flutter and Dart extensions appear to be broken on VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, sdk

I opened VSCode a few days ago to continue work on a Flutter project, unfortunately, the Flutter and Dart usually take a while to start(2-3 minutes), but this time,the extensions failed to initialize, and I'm left without the tools that come with the extensions .[screenshot of the current state of things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rofeJ.png)

#### Over the past few days, I have,

- Deleted and re-installed the Flutter SDK(now its  3.3.7, Dart 2.18.4)
- Deleted and re-installed VSCode(used to be a snap, now a .deb)
- Uninstalled and re-installed the Flutter and Dart extensions(multiple times, restarted VSCode each time)

- Ran said project directly from the terminal to be sure I had the flutter tool correctly installed(*flutter run* and *flutter build apk* ran fine, with no errors)

Please find the results of 'flutter doctor -v' below

```
 Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS 5.15.0-52-generic,
    locale en_NG)
    • Flutter version 3.3.7 on channel stable at
      /home/alabi/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision e99c9c7cd9 (7 days ago), 2022-11-01 16:59:00 -0700
    • Engine revision 857bd6b74c
    • Dart version 2.18.4
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /home/alabi/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/alabi/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /home/alabi/.jdks/openjdk-18.0.1.1/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
      more details.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at
    google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.52.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux • linux-x64 • Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS 5.15.0-52-generic
```

The CLI command, 'flutter --version' returns

```
Flutter 3.3.7 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e99c9c7cd9 (7 days ago) • 2022-11-01 16:59:00 -0700
Engine • revision 857bd6b74c
Tools • Dart 2.18.4 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

All of this leads me to believe the Flutter SDK is installed correctly and the problem is with VSCode and the extensions

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's telling you that your android license status is unknown and how to fix it. Not sure if that is the problem but you should clear that error.

Comment: Thanks Graham, i'll try, but that's probably a whole question on it's own, it says i need to install SDK mamager, which I already have. It's never been a problem since though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

> If something in the extension is corrupt you could try uninstalling the extensions and then deleting them from ~/.vscode/extensions (the ones starting dart-code) and then reinstall.

From DartCode's GitHub, read the issue and fix [here](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4259) if you're still confused

Answer (score 1):

For macOS this worked for me:

1. Open terminal
2. Go to **~/.vscode/extensions**
3. Delete all extensions which name starts with `dart-code` (*use rm -r*)
4. Open `extensions.js` with any text editor.
5. Remove all entries wihich name starts with `dart-code`
6. Reload Visual Studio Code (Make sur you use **Quit** option to completely close the app before launching it again)
7. Install extensions again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use official extensions for Flutter/Dart. They are created by Dart Code.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, however, if you view the attached screenshot in the first paragraph, you'll see that I've done just that

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to install an old version of dart extensión cause my flutter extensión said "No activated" until i installed the old dart extension

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem,
solved it by uninstalling vscode and vscodeFonts and removing the folder .vscode in my C:\User folder (i am on windows)

Then reinstall vscode

Comment: uninstalling may not be an ideal solution.